# 'A start job is running for wait for network to be configured'

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan

Just upgraded a headless server to 22.04.4 LTS.

Every time I start up now, I get this annoying 2 minute delay.

EDIT: to be more specific, I tried `sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service`. No change.

My `netplan` looks like this:

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # For more information, see netplan(5).
    network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
       enp0s31f6:
         dhcp4: no
         dhcp6: no
         addresses: 
            - 10.0.1.22/24
            - fd32:bb51:1f4d::9d9/128
         gateway4: 10.0.1.1
         nameservers:
           addresses: [10.0.1.1]
```

My LAN router assigns static IPs.

There is also a file `50-cloud-init.yaml` in `/etc/netplan` — dunno if that matters.

**How can I fix this?**

Thx

Comment: "Nothing works" - you don't tell us what you've tried. Did you disable `systemd-networkd-wait-online`, or modify your `netplan`?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Yes, tried `sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service`. Tried fiddling with the router. Looked at `netplan` but all discussions I found w.r.t. that were vague. Somebody suggested `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` but that file doesn't exist on my system.

Comment: OK, I tried editing `netplan` to define an IPv6 static address, as defined by my router, but this has no effect.

The system still hangs for two minutes on statup.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post your complete netplan config.

Comment: OK, I've added the `netplan` and a few details, above.